# Proper way to use Angular EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events

In my simplified scenario there is a `parent` component, which contains all the business logic.

The `parent` creates a `child` component which is only responsible to display a list of buttons.

I want to handle the click events for such buttons in the `parent`, but, using the suggested `EventEmitter` pattern I'm forced to use a useless `switch case` in the `parent`, in order to detect which button is pressed.

It would be much easier to directly pass the callbacks as input of the `child`, but I think it's not a good practice. Also these callbacks, as far as I can see, are executed in the context of the child, which is not the desired outcome.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to achieve my needs? Or I'm completely approaching the problem in a wrong way?

**The parent:**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "parent",
  template: ` <child
      [buttons]="buttons"
      (click)="onButtonClick($event)"
    ></child>
    <span>{{ description }}</span>`
})
export class ParentComponent {
  description = "";
  buttons = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];

  onButtonClick(button: string) {
    switch (button) {
      case "foo":
        this.description = "Calling foo()";
        this.foo();
        break;
      case "bar":
        this.description = "Calling bar()";
        this.bar();
        break;
      case "baz":
        this.description = "Calling baz()";
        this.baz();
        break;
    }
  }

  foo() {}
  bar() {}
  baz() {}
}
```

**The child:**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "child",
  template: ` <span *ngFor="let button of buttons">
    <button (click)="onClick(button)">{{ button }}</button>
  </span>`
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() buttons: string[];

  @Output() click = new EventEmitter<string>();

  onClick(button: string) {
    this.click.emit(button);
  }
}
```

**And a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-parm-dj35og?file=/src/app/child.component.ts).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emit what-ever

//parent

```
@Component({
  selector: "parent",
  template: ` <child
      [buttons]="buttons" (click)="$event()"
    ></child>
    <span>{{ description }}</span>`
})
export class ParentComponent {
  description = "";
  buttons = [
    { name: "foo", callback: this.foo},
    { name: "bar", callback: this.bar},
    { name: "baz", callback: this.baz},
  ];
  foo(){}
  bar(){}
  baz(){}
}
```

//child

```
@Component({
  selector: "child",
  template: ` <span *ngFor="let button of buttons">
    <button (click)="onClick(button)">{{ button.name }}</button>
  </span>`
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() buttons: any[];

  @Output() click = new EventEmitter<any>();

  onClick(button: any) {
    this.click.emit(button.callback);
  }
}
```

**Update** Sound "bizarro" pass a function and execute using function(), but we need think that a function is only an object.

Imagine you define two functions

```
function1(){console.log("I'm function 1")}
function2(){console.log("I'm function 1")}
```

In an event click we call to a function

```
click()
{
   const mainFunction=this.function1
   mainFunction() //execute the function1
}
```

or according a variable

```
click()
{
   const mainFunction=this.condicion?this.function1:this.function2
   mainFunction() //execute the function1 or the function2 
                  //if condition is true or false
}
```

The variables,object,arrays,functions... are physical stored in a memory position. the "name" of the variable, object, function... are only a "pointer" to this memory.

If we want, we could in the answer write

```
    <child [buttons]="buttons" (click)="executeFunction($event)"></child>

   executeFunction(mainFunction:any)
   {
         mainFunction()
   }
```

If we want we can type the function to give more clearity if all our function has no argument and no return anything, instead use this uggly "any" use

```
   executeFunction(mainFunction:()=>void)
   {
         mainFunction()
   }
```

And

```
@Output() click = new EventEmitter<()=>void>();
```

Comment: I like it, even if the syntax (click)="$event()" is weird to read. Just to understand: is this one supposed to be a good design or a workaround to solve my issue due to a wrong component modeling?

Comment: @c.bear, A function is like another object. I try to explain (I'm not pretty sure I get it) in the update of the answer. Well, really a group of buttons generally makes some pretty close action, e.g. all of them route to a page, or all of them change one color... So generally call to the same function with different parameters. If it's your case, think that you choose your array "buttons " of object  and you can add so many properties you need and emit the own button

Answer (score 0):

You could think about providing the callbacks within an object array instead of the string array.

Edited Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-brahmagupta-ueg4nv

**The Parent**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "parent",
  template: ` <child
      [buttons]="buttons"
    ></child>
    <span>{{ description }}</span>`
})
export class ParentComponent {
  description = "";
  buttons = [
    { name: "foo", callback: () => { this.description = "Calling foo()" } },
    // bar
    // baz
  ];
}
```

**The child**

```
@Component({
  selector: "child",
  template: ` <span *ngFor="let button of buttons">
    <button (click)="button.callback()">{{ button.name }}</button>
  </span>`
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() buttons: MyButton[];
}
```

**The interface**

```
interface MyButton {
  name: string,
  callback: () => void;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the possible solution I mentioned in my question. But it seems like I'm breaking the good principle Angular tries to enforce using emitters. Basically it's just skipping the event binding. What would stop me to apply this to every other simple event like "click"?